# Inflated view has no height

Tags: android, gridview

I am implementing an expandable recyclerview adapter in my app, everything is working perfectly except my expandable adapter has a gridview in it, in the gridview am am putting images, but it seems the expandable adapter is not being given height, when I predefine the height everything is working perfectly but I do not want to predefine it, I want it to wrap content here is my code

My Adapter XML

```
<FrameLayout
style="@style/commonListItemStyle"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/bg_swipe_item_neutral">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:foreground="?attr/selectableItemBackground">



<GridView
    android:id="@+id/expanded_grid"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    android:background="#ecf0f1"
    android:numColumns="4"
    android:horizontalSpacing="3dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="3dp"
    android:listSelector="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"

    />


</FrameLayout>
```

my Adapter code

```
public class ExpandableCategoryAdapter extends ExpandableRecyclerAdapter<CategoryParentViewHolder, CategoryChildViewHolder> {
/**
 * Primary constructor. Sets up {@link #mParentItemList} and {@link #mItemList}.
 * <p>
 * Changes to {@link #mParentItemList} should be made through add/remove methods in
 * {@link ExpandableRecyclerAdapter}
 *
 * @param parentItemList List of all {@link ParentListItem} objects to be
 *                       displayed in the RecyclerView that this
 *                       adapter is linked to
 */
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private ImageInternalFetcher mImageFetcher;
private Context context;
public ExpandableCategoryAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ParentListItem> parentItemList) {
    super(parentItemList);
    this.context = context;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    mImageFetcher = new ImageInternalFetcher(context, 300);
}

@Override
public CategoryParentViewHolder onCreateParentViewHolder(ViewGroup parentViewGroup) {
    View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.parent_category, parentViewGroup, false);
    return new CategoryParentViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public CategoryChildViewHolder onCreateChildViewHolder(ViewGroup childViewGroup) {
    View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.preview_child, childViewGroup, false);
    return new CategoryChildViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindParentViewHolder(CategoryParentViewHolder parentViewHolder, int position, ParentListItem parentListItem) {
    ExpandableCategoryItem item = (ExpandableCategoryItem) parentListItem;
    parentViewHolder.mCrimeTitleTextView.setText(item.getmDescription());
}

@Override
public void onBindChildViewHolder(CategoryChildViewHolder childViewHolder, int position, Object childListItem) {
    ChildItem data = (ChildItem) childListItem;
    ImageGalleryAdapter adapter = new ImageGalleryAdapter(context);

    if(data.getImgUri() != null) {
        for (String item : data.getImgUri()) {
            try {
                adapter.add(new ImageObject(Uri.parse(item)));
            }catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        childViewHolder.gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }


}




class ViewHolder {

    ImageObject mImage;
    ImageView mThumbnail;
}

public class ImageGalleryAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ImageObject> {

    public ImageGalleryAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.adapter_grid_expanded, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.mThumbnail = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pp__thumbnail_image);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        ImageObject image = getItem(position);



        if (holder.mImage == null || !holder.mImage.equals(image)) {
            mImageFetcher.loadImage(image.getImagePath(), holder.mThumbnail);
            holder.mImage = image;
        }
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Layout containing Recycler

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout    
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/parentCord"
android:background="@drawable/repeatinggiftly"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="192dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
        app:contentScrim="@color/google_lightblue"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/clothes"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />
            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/actionbar_gradient_dark" />
        </FrameLayout>
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/anim_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

  </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>








 <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/recyclerParent"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingRight="10dp"

app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
android:background="@android:color/transparent">


<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
    app:cardElevation="2dp"
    app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
    app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayou">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/scrollableview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
   />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


 </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:id="@+id/fabAddItem"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_add"
    app:backgroundTint="@color/accent"
    app:layout_anchor="@+id/appbar"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />

  </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Show the layout containing the `RecyclerView` please.

Comment: Layout with recyclerview has been added

Comment: You don't need a second `CoordinatorLayout`, and I don't think you need the `CardView` either. Typically cards appear as children of `RecyclerView`s, not as parents of them. Try it with just the `RecyclerView` after the `AppBarLayout`, and make sure to give it `match_parent` for both dimensions and the `appbar_scrolling_view_behavior`. If you need to adjust some padding or backgrounds, do it on the `RecyclerView` itself or just wrap it in something simple like a `FrameLayout`.

Comment: i have done as advised and to no avail